# Create Dynamic Copy of Existing Assembly/Module

Tags: c#, reflection, dynamic-assemblies

Is it possible to create a dynamic copy of an assembly or module/class?  I was able to easily find how to create a dynamic assembly or module from scratch using `AssemblyBuilder`/`ModuleBuilder` (as seen [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.emit.methodrental.swapmethodbody(v=vs.100).aspx)), but is there a way to create a copy of an existing assembly or type as its respective Builder type?

### Edit 1

For example, say you have a standard Console Application with the obligatory `Program` class and `Main` method and you add another class to the project, called 'A'.  My goal is to create a dynamic copy of the `A` class within the `Main` method using `ModuleBuilder` or something like it.

### Edit 2

The reason I want to make a copy of class `A`, is because I would like an *exact* duplicate of class `A`, including methods, fields, properties, etc., but created dynamically.  What I *don't* want, is to have to manually create the type and all of its members (methods, fields, properties, etc.) using TypeBuilder/CodeDom, since, in some cases, I may not know all of the details about a class and its inner workings or the class may be large and tedious/impossible to reproduce using this method.

Hopefully some pseudocode can illustrate what I'm looking for:

```
// create AssemblyBuilder using the assembly of the A class so you end up with a
// dynamic copy of the assembly
AssemblyBuilder ab = new AssemblyBuilder(Assembly.GetAssembly(typeof(A)));

// get the Type as a TypeBuilder from the AssemblyBuilder
TypeBuilder tb = ab.GetModule("Test.exe").GetType(typeof(A).FullName);
```

I'd basically just like to box an `Assembly` as an `AssemblyBuilder` or `Type` as a `TypeBuilder`.  I also don't need to be able to save the assembly.

Comment: Do you mean you will generate code from class A and generate an assembly?

Comment: I only really need the generated code from class A, but if generating an assembly is needed to achieve that, then it doesn't matter.

Answer (score 0):

From your comments above, look like you would like generate code C# and can compile it as well.
If so I suggest you should look at CodeDom instead of using `AssemblyBuilder` and `ModuleBuilder`. It will straight forward and easy to understand.

The links below will help you:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/650ax5cx.aspx

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/7119/Compiling-with-CodeDom

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/davidebb/archive/2009/06/03/codedom-vs-t4-two-approaches-to-code-generation.aspx

BTW, if you would like to build a tool similar Reflector which will load outside assemblies and generate back to code then you should use CodeDom as well.

Take reference from here:

https://www.simple-talk.com/dotnet/.net-framework/-.net-reflector-meets-the-codedom/

Comment: I added some more clarification above.

Comment: None of these links addresses how to do this with an existing assembly, as far as I can tell.